# If $f(x)=x^4\sin\frac1x$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$, for which $n$ does $f(x)$ have a (continuous) $n$-th derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let
> $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
>       x^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq0 \\
>       0 & x =0
>    \end{cases}$
>
> For which $n$ does $f^{(n)}$ exist? When is $f^{(n)}$ continuous? Prove your answers!

What I have done:
I thought about using Taylor series for this, and differentiating each term, but didn't know how to incorporate the piecewise part. Am I on the right track?

When $x\neq 0$: $$f'(x)=4\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)x^3-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)x^2=x^2\left(4\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)x-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

When $x=0$:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}=0$$

Comment: You should add your thoughts to your question.

Comment: @Aryadeva done, thank you!

Comment: Forget Taylor series. Now start with $n=1$. Does $f'$ exist? What is it?

Comment: You could calculate $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, etc, until you find one that cannot be computed.  First compute $f'(x)$.  Treat the cases $x = 0$ and $x \ne 0$ separately.  You do $x \ne 0$ the usual way.  You do $x = 0$ using the definition of derivative.  Then go onto compute $f''(x)$.  You can't do the next derivative at $x = 0$ until the previous derivative has been completely computed.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I tried that, and the first few seem to be computable. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Show your work.  Then we can help you more.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I showed my work for the first derivative—can you help me out with the second one? Looking back, I'm pretty sure what I did was wrong.

Comment: So you want to do the same again.  Note, do some simplifying with $f'(x)$ when $x \ne 0$.  That will make it easier when you compute $f''(x)$.

Comment: Also, write $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^4 \sin(1/h) - 0} h $.  It simplifies things.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith How would I simplify when $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Multiply it out: $4x^3 \sin(1/x) - x^2 \cos(1/x)$.  It will be less work to differentiate it.

Comment: Oh, that's what you had before you factored.  Don't factor.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith how did you get that $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}$? How do I find the second derivative this way?

Comment: It is just $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)} h.$

Comment: Now do $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(h) - f'(0)} h $.

Comment: to find $f''(0)$.